# user principal/service principal in Office 365

Tags: powershell, acs, office365

When I use the provisioning api for Office 365 (via connect-msolservice or via https://provisioningapi.microsoftonline.com/provisioningwebservice.svc) I am using a user name and password. When I connect, I automate using powershell or via the web service and to office 365 deployment stuff (like federating/unfederating a local domain.)

The problem I am facing is that passwords will eventually expire and my service will be disrupted. I am looking for a way to prevent this. Question is:

- Can I use Service Principal Names (say belonging to the "Company Administrator" role) to connect to the provisioning api? (ie, like the Graph APIs uses SPNs) Basically substitute the user/password with the service principal/password? I think SPNs password have a longer duration so I don't worry about password expiration.

-if this is not possible, is there a way to query, given an account in Office 365/Azure AD, if it's password is about to expire?

Thanks
Den H.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the password to never expire for this account. Not exactly what you want but it works.

Comment: Unfortunately, my place of work will not allow that '-) I'm looking for ways to reduce Ops overhead each time passwords are required to change.